# Testing (if..Else if...Else) statement (not working)

Tags: java

Testing an if else statement that does not seem to be working
Assuming it has something to do with possibly changing the IF else to the getter instead of setter?
or something to do with the variable returning an INT instead of string? 
little confused been rearranging and modifying this code for a while now and cant get it to work

```
//package Driver2;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Person{
private String name;
private String address;
private String number;
private int customerPurchase = 0;

//Constructors
public Person(String name, String address, String number, int customerPurchase){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.number = number;
    this.customerPurchase = customerPurchase;
}

public Person(){}

//Accessors
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return this.address;
}

public String getNumber(){
    return this.number;
}

public int getcustomerPurchase(){
    return this.customerPurchase;
}

//Mutators
public void setName(String n){
    this.name = n;
}

public void setAddress(String a){
    this.address = a;
}

public void setNumber(String n){
    this.number = n;
}

public void setcustomerPurchase(int a){
    this.customerPurchase = a;
}
public void setcustomerDiscount(int r)
{
   r =  this.customerPurchase;
    if (r > 500)
    {
        System.out.print("5%");
    }
    else if (r >= 1000)
    {
        System.out.print("6%");
    }
    else if (r >= 1500)
    {
        System.out.print("7%");
    }
    else if (r >= 2000)
    {
        System.out.print("10%");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }
}

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Customer extends Person{
private String customerNumber;
private boolean recieveMail;
private int customerDiscount;

//Constructors
public Customer(String name, String address, String number, String customerN, boolean rm, int customerPurchase) {
    super(name, address, number, customerPurchase);
    this.customerNumber = customerN;
    this.recieveMail = rm;
}

public Customer(){}

//Accessors
public String getCustomerNumber(){
    return this.customerNumber;
}

public boolean getRecieveMail(){
    return this.recieveMail;
}
public int getcustomerDiscount()
{
    return customerDiscount;
}

//Mutators
public void setCustomerNumber(String c){
    this.customerNumber = c;
}

public void setRecieveMail(boolean r){
    this.recieveMail = r;
}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Driver1 extends Customer
{
//private int customerPurchase = 0;

//Constructors
   /* public Driver1(String name, String address, String number, String customerN, boolean rm, int customerPurchase)
{
    super();
    this.customerPurchase = customerPurchase;
    //this.customerDiscount = customerDiscount;
}*/
    public Driver1(String name, String address, String number, String customerN, boolean rm, int customerPurchase) {
    //super(name, address, number, customerPurchase, customerN, rm);
    //this.customerPurchase = customerN;
    //this.customerDiscount = pc;
}

public Driver1()
{}

//Accessors
/*
public int getcustomerDiscount()
{
    return this.customerDiscount;
}
/*
@Override
public int getcustomerPurchase()
{
    return this.customerPurchase;
}


//Mutators

@Override
public void setcustomerPurchase(int c)
{
    this.customerPurchase = c;
}*/

/*
public void setcustomerDiscount(int r)
{
    this.customerPurchase = r;
    if (r >= 500)
    {
        System.out.print("5%");
    }
    else if (r >= 1000)
    {
        System.out.print("6%");
    }
    else if (r >= 1500)
    {
        System.out.print("7%");
    }
    else if (r >= 2000)
    {
        System.out.print("10%");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
*/
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class Main
{

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name of customer:");
    String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter address of customer:");
    String address1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter phone number of customer:");
    String number1 = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter customer number:");
    String customerNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter yes/no -- does the customer want to recieve mail?:");
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();
    boolean recieveMail = (answer.equals("yes"));
    System.out.print("Enter amount customer has spent:");
    int customerPurchase = scanner.nextInt();

    Customer customer = new Customer(name1, address1, number1, customerNumber, recieveMail, customerPurchase);

    System.out.println("\nCustomer: ");
    System.out.println("Name: "+customer.getName());
    System.out.println("Address: "+customer.getAddress());
    System.out.println("Phone Number: "+customer.getNumber());
    System.out.println("Customer Number: "+customer.getCustomerNumber());
    System.out.println("Recieve Mail?: "+customer.getRecieveMail());
    System.out.println("Amount Purchased: "+customer.getcustomerPurchase());
    System.out.println("Percent off:  "+customer.getcustomerDiscount());

}
}
```

Comment: If `r` is equal `1999`, then `r` is greater than `500`. This means your whole statement effectively degrades to `if (r > 500) {...} else {...}`, and no other branches will ever execute.

Comment: Also, _does not seem to be working_ is not a good description of the problem.

Comment: M. Prokhorov is right. Check for the biggest values first.

Comment: @blackstar In the `Person` class you have `setcustomerDiscount()` but the `customerDiscount` field is in the `Customer` class. And then you never actually call the `setcustomerDiscount()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have pasted require some changes actually.Assuming you need to return the discount percentage based on the customer input you need to do the following changes.

1) You have a `setCustomerDiscount` in `Person` class but the entity you are dealing here is of `Customer` type so you need to add the `setCustomerDiscount` in the `Customer` class instead of Person class.

2) As you want to show the percentage in String(as per your sysout statements/ you can also change to Int as required) you need to change the return type to String instead of Int.

3) Another thing is your order of the if/else if conditions should be in descending order.

Once you fix them, you can get your output as expected.
Below I have made those changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Person{
private String name;
private String address;
private String number;
private int customerPurchase = 0;

//Constructors
public Person(String name, String address, String number, int customerPurchase){
  this.name = name;
  this.address = address;
  this.number = number;
  this.customerPurchase = customerPurchase;
}

public Person(){}

//Accessors
public String getName(){
  return this.name;
}

public String getAddress(){
  return this.address;
}

public String getNumber(){
  return this.number;
}

public int getcustomerPurchase(){
  return this.customerPurchase;
}

//Mutators
public void setName(String n){
  this.name = n;
}

public void setAddress(String a){
  this.address = a;
}

public void setNumber(String n){
  this.number = n;
}

public void setcustomerPurchase(int a){
  this.customerPurchase = a;
}
public void setcustomerDiscount(int r)
{

}

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Customer extends Person{
private String customerNumber;
private boolean recieveMail;
private String customerDiscount;

//Constructors
public Customer(String name, String address, String number, String customerN, boolean rm, int customerPurchase) {
  super(name, address, number, customerPurchase);
  this.customerNumber = customerN;
  this.recieveMail = rm;
}

public Customer(){}

//Accessors
public String getCustomerNumber(){
  return this.customerNumber;
}

public boolean getRecieveMail(){
  return this.recieveMail;
}
public String getcustomerDiscount()
{
  return customerDiscount;
}

//Mutators
public void setCustomerNumber(String c){
  this.customerNumber = c;
}

public void setRecieveMail(boolean r){
  this.recieveMail = r;
}

public void setcustomerDiscount(int r)
{
  String customerDiscount = "";

  if (r >= 2000)
  {
    customerDiscount="10%";
      System.out.print("10%");
  }
  else if (r >= 1500)
  {
    customerDiscount="7%";
      System.out.print("7%");
  }
  else if (r >= 1000)
  {
   customerDiscount="6%";
      System.out.print("6%");
  }
  else if (r > 500)
  {
    customerDiscount="5%";
      System.out.print("5%");
  }
  else
  {

      System.out.print("");
  }
  this.customerDiscount = customerDiscount;
}
}

public class TestMain
{

public static void main(String args[]){

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter name of customer:");
  String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter address of customer:");
  String address1 = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter phone number of customer:");
  String number1 = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter customer number:");
  String customerNumber = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter yes/no -- does the customer want to recieve mail?:");
  String answer = scanner.nextLine();
  boolean recieveMail = (answer.equals("yes"));
  System.out.print("Enter amount customer has spent:");
  int customerPurchase = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.close();

  Customer customer = new Customer(name1, address1, number1, customerNumber, recieveMail, customerPurchase);

  System.out.println("\nCustomer: ");
  System.out.println("Name: "+customer.getName());
  System.out.println("Address: "+customer.getAddress());
  System.out.println("Phone Number: "+customer.getNumber());
  System.out.println("Customer Number: "+customer.getCustomerNumber());
  System.out.println("Recieve Mail?: "+customer.getRecieveMail());
  System.out.println("Amount Purchased: "+customer.getcustomerPurchase());
  customer.setcustomerDiscount(customerPurchase);
  System.out.println("Percent off:  "+ customer.getcustomerDiscount());


}
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I would most likely put the if/else logic in its own service class and call its method from ``setCustomerDiscount()`` for expandability.

Comment: Still a little off, imma dissect what you've done and work with the problem more, but this puts me on the right track getting it to spit out a working statement. 
"You are a godsend !!"
once i work with this more if i can get this 100% perfect i will post the final results. 
thank you Santossh

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a logical problem. Simply order the discount formula in reverse.
Catch the big numbers first:

```
if  r >= 2000  print 10%
else if  r >= 1500  print 7%
else if  r >= 1000  print 6%
else if  r >= 500   print 5%
else print nothing
```

I hope that helps you

Comment: Thank you for helping, rearranged, seems to still output 0.
Im pretty sure its trying to send out an INT instead of a string output, just need to find were to rearrange that